Speed up script - Google sheet
i have some problems with script speed after running the code.
This is my first script and I dont know how to write it easier or how to put those rows on top in my database except of last(i dont know if it could help.).
This is my code. The idea is, that i created the form where people can write their skills. There are 30 kind of skills, each personal skill need to be in separate row with name.
that means i need to add 30 row to my database when i click on submit data. And it takes 10 min to write it.
//Function to submit the data to Database sheet
function submitData(){
//declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shForm=ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var database=ss.getSheetByName("Employee Data");

const fieldsRangeTA  = ["C2","D2","A5","B5","C5","D5","E5"]    
const fieldValuesTA = fieldsRangeTA.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesTA)
const fieldsRangeTA  = ["C2","D2","A5","B5","C5","D5","E5"]    
const fieldValuesTA = fieldsRangeTA.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesTA)
const fieldsRangeTB  = ["C2","D2","A6","B6","C6","D6","E6"]  
const fieldValuesTB = fieldsRangeTB.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesTB)
const fieldsRangeTC  = ["C2","D2","A7","B7","C7","D7","E7"]   
const fieldValuesTC = fieldsRangeTC.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesTC)
const fieldsRangeT1  = ["C2","D2","A8","B8","C8","D8","E8"]    
const fieldValuesT1 = fieldsRangeT1.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT1)
const fieldsRangeT2  = ["C2","D2","A9","B9","C9","D9","E9"]    
const fieldValuesT2 = fieldsRangeT2.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT2)
const fieldsRangeT3  = ["C2","D2","A10","B10","C10","D10","E10"]  
const fieldValuesT3 = fieldsRangeT3.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT3)
const fieldsRangeT4  = ["C2","D2","A11","B11","C11","D11","E11"]    
const fieldValuesT4 = fieldsRangeT4.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT4)
const fieldsRangeT5  = ["C2","D2","A12","B12","C12","D12","E12"]   
const fieldValuesT5 = fieldsRangeT5.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT5)
const fieldsRangeT6  = ["C2","D2","A13","B13","C13","D13","E13"]  
const fieldValuesT6 = fieldsRangeT6.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT6)
const fieldsRangeT7  = ["C2","D2","A14","B14","C14","D14","E14"]    
const fieldValuesT7 = fieldsRangeT7.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT7)
const fieldsRangeT8 =  ["C2","D2","A15","B15","C15","D15","E15"]   
const fieldValuesT8 = fieldsRangeT8.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT8)
const fieldsRangeT9 =  ["C2","D2","A16","B16","C16","D16","E16"]    
const fieldValuesT9 = fieldsRangeT9.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT9)
const fieldsRangeT10  = ["C2","D2","A17","B17","C17","D17","E17"]  
const fieldValuesT10 = fieldsRangeT10.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT10)
const fieldsRangeT11  = ["C2","D2","A18","B18","C18","D18","E18"]  
const fieldValuesT11 = fieldsRangeT11.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT11)
const fieldsRangeT12  = ["C2","D2","A19","B19","C19","D19","E19"]  
const fieldValuesT12 = fieldsRangeT12.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT12)
const fieldsRangeT13  = ["C2","D2","A20","B20","C20","D20","E20"]
const fieldValuesT13 = fieldsRangeT13.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT13)
const fieldsRangeT14  = ["C2","D2","A21","B21","C21","D21","E21"]  
const fieldValuesT14 = fieldsRangeT14.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT14)
const fieldsRangeT15  = ["C2","D2","A22","B22","C22","D22","E22"]  
const fieldValuesT15 = fieldsRangeT15.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT15)
const fieldsRangeT16  = ["C2","D2","A23","B23","C23","D23","E23"]  
const fieldValuesT16 = fieldsRangeT16.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT16)
const fieldsRangeT17  = ["C2","D2","A24","B24","C24","D24","E24"]
const fieldValuesT17 = fieldsRangeT17.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT17)
const fieldsRangeT18  = ["C2","D2","A25","B25","C25","D25","E25"]  
const fieldValuesT18 = fieldsRangeT18.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT18)
const fieldsRangeT19  = ["C2","D2","A26","B26","C26","D26","E26"]  
const fieldValuesT19 = fieldsRangeT19.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT19)
const fieldsRangeT20  = ["C2","D2","A27","B27","C27","D27","E27"] 
const fieldValuesT20 = fieldsRangeT20.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT20)
const fieldsRangeT21 =  ["C2","D2","A28","B28","C28","D28","E28"]   
const fieldValuesT21 = fieldsRangeT21.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT21)
const fieldsRangeT22 =  ["C2","D2","A29","B29","C29","D29","E29"]  
const fieldValuesT22 = fieldsRangeT22.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT22)
const fieldsRangeT23  = ["C2","D2","A30","B30","C30","D30","E30"]   
const fieldValuesT23 = fieldsRangeT23.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT23)
const fieldsRangeT24  = ["C2","D2","A31","B31","C31","D31","E31"]  
const fieldValuesT24 = fieldsRangeT24.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT24)
const fieldsRangeT25  = ["C2","D2","A33","B33","C33","D33","E33"]  
const fieldValuesT25 = fieldsRangeT25.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT25)
const fieldsRangeT26  = ["C2","D2","A34","B34","C34","D34","E34"]
const fieldValuesT26 = fieldsRangeT26.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesT26)
}

I tried to create some script that add 30 empty rows after the head of database but i couldn't figure out how to submit data to those 30 empty rows (the new record was always written down on the bottom of database). Please help
thanks

You can replace this:
const fieldsRangeTA  = ["C2","D2","A5","B5","C5","D5","E5"]    
const fieldValuesTA = fieldsRangeTA.map(f=>shForm.getRange(f).getValue())
database.appendRow(fieldValuesTA)

with this:
const [[,,a,b,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[c,d,e,f,g]] = sheet.getRange("A2:E5").getValues(); 
database.appendRow([a,b,c,d,e,f]);

There is a way to automate this even further but it's a lot of work.  If you wish to try then you might like to take a look at this Hopefully, someone will come up with a better solution.

Modification points:

In your script, const fieldsRangeTA and const fieldValuesTA are declared 2 times. So, I think that an error occurs. But you say And it takes 10 min to write it.. So, I'm worried that you might have misplaced your script.
When I saw your script, appendRow is multiply used. And, getValue() is used in a loop. These might be the reason for your current issue. Ref (Author: me)
If your showing script is a correct script, when I saw your script, it seems that you want to copy the values from "A5:E34" to the last row of the destination sheet by adding "C2:D2" to the header column and removing the row "A32:E32".

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shForm = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var database = ss.getSheetByName("Employee Data");

  // I modified the below script.
  var h = shForm.getRange("C2:D2").getValues();
  var v = shForm.getRange("A5:E34").getValues();
  var srcValues = v.map(r => [...h[0], ...r]).filter((_, i) => i != 27);
  database.getRange(database.getLastRow() + 1, 1, srcValues.length, srcValues[0].length).setValues(srcValues);
}


When I tested this script, I confirmed that the result of your showing script by removing one const fieldsRangeTA and const fieldValuesTA is the same as the result of this script.

Note:

This modified script supposes that your showing script works by removing one const fieldsRangeTA and const fieldValuesTA. Please be careful about this.

References:

getValues()
setValues(values)
map()

